# In NestJs, how to inject a service based on its interface?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, nestjs

I have the next module: payment.module.ts

```
@Module({
  controllers: [PaymentController],
})
export class PaymentModule {}
```

And in the next service I want to have access to a service based on an interface

payment.service.ts

```
export class PaymentService {
   constructor(private readonly notificationService: NotificationInterface,
}
```

notification.interface.ts

```
export interface NotificationInterface {
  // some method definitions
}
```

notification.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationService implements NotificationInterface {
  // some implemented methods
}
```

The question is how do I inject `NotificationService` based on `NotificationInterface`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is the solution I found... using Interfaces as value types is not possible as they only exist during development. After transpiling interfaces no longer exist resulting in empty object values. There is a solution for your problem though using string keys as provide values and the inject decorator:

payment.module.ts

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'NotificationInterface',
      useClass: NotificationService
    }
  ]
})
export class PaymentModule {}
```

payment.service.ts

```
export class PaymentService {
   constructor(@Inject('NotificationInterface') private readonly notificationService: NotificationInterface,
}
```

Comment: Good answer, this is the approach I use and the recommended NestJS of solving this problem

Comment: There is a nice blog for this implementation. https://jasonwhite.xyz/posts/2020/10/20/nestjs-dependency-injection-decoupling-services-with-interfaces/

Comment: @BurcuGeneci could you suggest how to resolve these kind of dependency in unit test . I am after making similar changes reading the blog you mentioned, i am getting this error:`Nest could not find MyService element (this provider does not exist in the current context)`

Comment: @Gabriel can you let me know how to add these kind of dependencies when writing unit tests.?

Comment: Thanks for the example, helped me figure out how to solve my injection jungle :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this when there are multiple implementations?
I want to get all services that implement this interface, or have this key?

Comment: @Berethor if useClass doesn't work you can supply the instance you want using useFactory: () => {return new ConcreteClass()}

Answer (score 17):

As was mentioned by Gabriel, you cannot use interfaces since they are not present at runtime, but you *can* use an **abstract class**. They are available at runtime, so they can be used as your dependency injection token.

In Typescript, [class delcarations also create types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#using-a-class-as-an-interface), so you can also *implement* them, you don't have to extend them.

Following your example, you could do the following:

notification.interface.ts

```
export abstract class NotificationInterface {
  abstract send(): Promise<void>;
  // ... other method definitions
}
```

notification.service.ts

```js
export class NotificationService implements NotificationInterface {
  async send() {...}
}
```

Then in your module, provide it like so:

```js
import NotificationInterface from "..."
import NotificationService from "..."

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NotificationInterface,
      useClass: NotificationService
    }
  ]
})
export class PaymentModule {}
```

And finally, use the injected service via the interface in payments.service.ts

```js
export class PaymentService {
   constructor(private readonly notificationService: NotificationInterface) {}
}
```

Now you don't need to provide any custom tokens (as strings or symbols) that are somewhat "unrelated" to your class implementation (and only a DI construct), but you can use the structure from your OOP model.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. I have implemented the interfaces in your way and it works.

Comment: How can I choose which implementation to use if I have more? I don't want to put it in my service class (`PayementService` here) but rather configure it outside of the use site.

Comment: The wiring of the dependencies happens in the modules @AdamArold. The PaymentService should not need to know which notification service it is using.