# NestJS inject custom TypeOrm repository based on an Interface

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm currently working through the database integration [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#custom-repository) for NestJS using TypeOrm. In these docs there are examples that show how to inject a custom database repository using the app.module from NestJS. All of these examples inject classes using the actual type of the custom repository.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthorService {
  constructor(private authorRepository: AuthorRepository) {}
}
```

This code is injected via the app.modules by providing a import like such:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AuthorRepository])],
  controller: [AuthorController],
  providers: [AuthorService],
})
export class AuthorModule {}
```

This works well if you are fine with programming against an implementation, but I prefer to use an interface in my classes. I've already found the solution to injecting classes via an interface with NestJS in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63904194/6351280), but when I try to inject my custom repository like that, it doesn't seem to instanciate correctly and becomes undefined.

`(node:16658) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined`

Because of this, I assume you can only inject customRepositories via the `forFeature()` call in the app.module, but that won't allow me to use interfaces for injection, as far as I know. Is there any other way I can inject a custom TypeOrm repository without having the replace all my interfaces for the implementation of my custom repository? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

Here is my current code, I managed to get it to inject, but this still forces me to use the implementation instead of the interface each time I call the constructor. This is mainly an issue when testing due to mocking.

```
  @CommandHandler(FooCommand)
export class FooHandler
  implements ICommandHandler<FooCommand> {

  private fooRepository: IFooRepository; // Using Interface as a private property.
  private barEventBus: IEventBus;
  
  constructor(fooRepository: FooRepository,
     barEventBus: EventBus) { // Forced to use implementation in constructor for injection.
    this.fooRepository = fooRepository;
    this.barEventBus = barEventBus;
  }
```

```
@EntityRepository(FooEntity)
export class FooRepository extends Repository<FooEntity> implements IFooRepository {

  getFoo() {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(), TypeOrmModule.forFeature([FooRepository]],

  // Other module setup
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Why would you like to inject the custom repositories as interfaces instead of classes?

Comment: Because programming against the interface helps in keeping my code separated. The `forFeature()` injection forces me to use an implementation in my constructor, while I would like to keep that an interface.

Comment: @Jordi can you please include the code where you're trying to inject your custom repository so we can see the whole scenario

Comment: I've added my code. I got it to work with a class implementation, but I would still prefer to use a interface annotation in my constructor class, if possible ofcourse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work with using the `InjectRepository` decorator where you specify the Repository but then you type is as your interface instead and when testing you just provide the `IFooRepository`!

Example code:

```
  constructor(@InjectRepository(FooRepository) fooRepository: IFooRepository,
 barEventBus: EventBus) {
```

Comment: That's a bit of a half-assed solution tbh. It technically still makes the class dependent to the implementation (you import it and decorators are a part of the code as well). You cannot simply switch the implementation through DI but have to actually edit each class using the implementation.

Comment: Shocks me quite a bit that something like what OP asked about seems to be such an exotic use case for a top-notch TS framework. It is very basic clean code practice to program against interfaces. Some stuff which is recommended in the docs remembers me of the state of PHP frameworks 10 years ago.

Comment: Welcome to Javascript world ;) Jokes aside - it is quite common to program against interfaces in TS as well. Some people argue that it is not necessary due to the extra flexability that is provided. In the end it is personal preferences and both is totally valid and technically feasible.

Comment: And using Modules/Services you can inject a custom class that follows an interface. So your first comment is not really true.

Answer (score -1):

*Edit: This answer is crap, that abstract-class-as-interface hack used does not work out as the defined methods seem to be optional to implement despite being marked as abstract.*

Well, kind of got it working. Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74561702/913136 I used an abstract class as interface (you can actually `implement` it) for not being required to pass strings around as tokens. Only drawback is the misuse of the abstract class. Not sure yet if I like it.

Using an actual interface in the same way seems [not to be possible unfortunately.](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/43#issuecomment-300092490) Urgh.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ...dataSource.options,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Listing]),
  ],
  controllers: [ViewListingController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ListingRepository,
      useClass: TypeOrmListingRepository,
    },
  ],
})
```

makeshift interface:

```
import { Listing } from "./Listing";

export abstract class ListingRepository {
  abstract findMostRecent: () => Promise<Listing[]>;
}
```

implementation:

```
import { Listing, ListingRepository } from "../../Domain";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { Repository, DataSource } from "typeorm";

@Injectable()
export class TypeOrmListingRepository
  extends Repository<Listing>
  implements ListingRepository
{
  constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
    super(Listing, dataSource.createEntityManager());
  }

  findMostRecent() {
    return this.find({});
  }
}
```

```
import { Controller, Get } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ListingRepository } from "../Domain";

@Controller("listings")
export class ViewListingController {
  constructor(private readonly listingRepo: ListingRepository) {}

  @Get("/most-recent")
  listMostRecent() {
    return this.listingRepo.findMostRecent();
  }
}
```