Repository is being shown as undefined while I use reusable CRUD API in nestJS
I am trying to create a generic reusable CRUD that can be used in the program using NestJs, TypeORM and MySQL
While it shows no error initially and the table is created in the database as needed.
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +97ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] UserModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +50ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +4ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [RoutesResolver] UserController {/users}: +0ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/:id, GET} route +0ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/:id, PUT} route +0ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/users/:id, DELETE} route +1ms
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:14 am     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +1ms  

If I try to post dummy data using POSTMAN. It shows internal server error and the following error is shown.
Received data for creation: {
  name: 'John Doe',
  email: 'john.doe@example.com',
  password: 'password123'
}
Received Repository: undefined
[Nest] 8576  - 22/04/2024, 11:34:16 am   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'save')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'save')

This is my Base Repository. This is where my console.log has been done.
import { DeepPartial, FindOneOptions, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { BaseEntity } from '../base.entity/base.entity';
import { BadGatewayException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { QueryDeepPartialEntity } from 'typeorm/query-builder/QueryPartialEntity';


export abstract class BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity> {
  constructor(private readonly repository: Repository<T>) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<T[]> {
    return this.repository.find();
  }

  async findById(id: number): Promise<T> {
    const entity = await this.repository.findOne(id as FindOneOptions<T>);
    return entity; 
  }
  
async create(data: Partial<T>): Promise<T> {
  console.log('Received data for creation:', data);
  console.log('Received Repository:', this.repository);
  
    return await this.repository.save(data as DeepPartial<T>); 
  }

  async update(id: number, data: Partial<T>): Promise<T> {
    await this.repository.update(id, data as QueryDeepPartialEntity<T>);
    return this.findById(id);
  }

  async delete(id: number): Promise<void> {
    await this.repository.delete(id);
  }
}


This is the userRepository where it is to be used.
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { BaseRepository } from '../basic-crud/basic-repository';
import { User } from '../user.entity/user.entity';



export class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User> {
  constructor(   repository: Repository<User>) {
    super(repository);
  }
}


This is the User Module

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from 'src/services/user/user.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserRepository } from 'src/entities/user-repository/user-repository';
import { User } from 'src/entities/user.entity/user.entity';
import { UserController } from 'src/users/contollers/users/users.controller';


@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User,UserRepository])],
  providers: [UserService, UserRepository],
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [UserService, UserRepository],
})
export class UserModule {}

This is my App Module.
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserModule } from './module/users/users.module';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity/user.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'test',
      password: 'test',
      database: 'test',
      entities: [User],
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    UserModule,

  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}

I tried the @InjectRepository(Repository) Repository: Repository, mentioned in a few other similar questions {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63988821/nestjs-inject-custom-typeorm-repository-based-on-an-interface} but then I got the error that , User does not have meta-data.

I implemented IRepository in every Repository or Service present and it works
import { BaseEntity } from '../../entities/base.entity/base.entity';

export interface IRepository<T extends BaseEntity> {
  findAll(): Promise<T[]>;
  findById(id: number): Promise<T>;
  create(data: Partial<T>): Promise<T>;
  update(id: number, data: Partial<T>): Promise<T>;
  delete(id: number): Promise<void>;
}


